# Is there a way to allow guest OS to access internet while preventing host OS from accessing internet?

Tags: virtual-machine

Is there a way to allow guest OS to access internet while preventing host OS from accessing internet?

I want to access Internet from a guest OS while preventing the host OS from accessing internet, I want to do this to improve security. Is this possible?

I'm using Fedora host and the guest will any other Linux distro.

I'll be using VirtualBox

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your question to include the host and guest operating systems, as well as the virtualization software you intend to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a built-in feature of Guest Virtual Machines.

You are better to secure your Host system (which is quite feasible to do).

What you can try is the following:  Get a wireless USB card, implement USB pass-through from Host to Guest, set up wireless access in the Guest and ensure that it is working.

Once the Guest has wireless internet, turn off the Network Cards in the Host machine.

This is fairly cumbersome, but it should work, depending on your virtualizing application. It can be done in VMware Workstation.